# Centering a form in Delphi for PHP

Tags: php, delphi4php, rpcl

I have created a Delphi for PHP page in RadPHP. How can I make it center in the browser's window?
Is it possible to achieve it using only PHP code?

Comment: English it's not my native language, so that probably that's why I didn't understood... afaik DelphiForPhp it's and IDE/RAD that provide a graphical interface for the developer. At the far end, the final output should be php+html+css+js, it's that correct ? can you post also some code ? or a screenshot at least....

Comment: i just want the php code to make the page center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form cannot be centered by only using php, because php is server scripting language and it cannot determine the size of client area (available space) in the browser. This can only be done by using CSS and JavaScript. Try that approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can center an RPCL webpage with the following settings in your Page subclass:

- **Alignment**: `agCenter`.
- **Layout.Type**: `REL_XY_LAYOUT`.